# ¿Cómo se definen las preguntas de calidad?

Tags: discusión, wiki-de-comunidad, cierre-de-preguntas

El tutorial para realizar preguntas sugiere:

> El tono y la calidad de las preguntas formuladas durante estos siete días de versión beta privada tienen una importancia fundamental.
>
> Si la versión beta privada no produce suficientes preguntas de alta calidad de nivel de experto, no se procederá a la versión beta pública.

Las preguntas famosas de SO en inglés que tienen respuestas con un alto número de votos y que no necesariamente forman parte de la `Community Wiki` (a.k.a. EPIC Questions/Answers), ¿necesariamente entran en esta categoría?

Ejemplos:

1. [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)
2. [What is the name of the “-->” operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-the-operator)
3. [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794)
4. [When do you use the “this” keyword? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250/when-do-you-use-the-this-keyword)

La duda me surgió principalmente por la del parseo usando RegEx

Answer (score 3):

Básicamente se trata de seguir las recomendaciones del centro de ayuda: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). De forma resumida, una buena pregunta...

- Incluye toda la información relevante para identificar y reproducir el problema
- ...y **no** incluye información irrelevante que sólo añade ruido
- Está bien redactada, se entiende bien (incluyendo buena ortografía y gramática)
- Puede ser útil para más gente
- Tiene las etiquetas apropiadas
- Y lo obvio: está dentro de la temática del sitio, no es spam, no es ofensiva...

Yo personalmente pienso que a este respecto estamos haciendo un buen trabajo.

Comment: Y se asume que no es traducida la pregunta y la respuesta no? :P

Comment: La pregunta es una duda legítima de un usuario, y la respuesta es un resumen de un artículo del centro de ayuda que ya está traducido. Circulen. :-)

Comment: A veces es complicado hacer buenas preguntas cuando uno tiene poca experiencia en sitios como estos.