# ¿Hay que cerrar todas las preguntas subjetivas?

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas

Por ejemplo : [¿Es recomendable incluir varias clases en una sola clase java o es mejor trabajarlas por separado?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/50959/es-recomendable-incluir-varias-clases-en-una-sola-clase-java-o-es-mejor-trabaja)

Esta pregunta admite excelentes respuestas en que detallen tećnicas ámpliamente reconocidas como útiles en ingeniería del software. Que la cohesión, modularidad y división de tareas son recomendables tiene poca discusión. Una respuesta que explíque cómo afecta el uso de varias clases a esas cuestiones sería útil.
También puede recibir respuestas de baja calidad que sean muy opinables. Pero todas las preguntas pueden recibir respuestas de baja calidad, si no por ese motivo por otros.

Comment: Te refieres a todas las preguntas subjetivas, pero tu preocupación es por una sola pregunta, con argumentos bien fundamentados. ¿Se puede solicitar que esta pregunta sea reabierta con estos argumentos, sin que este ejemplo puntual y específico sea usado para una generalización?

Comment: No pongas palabras en mi boca @toledano. Por supuesto que me preocupan otras preguntas subjetivas.

Comment: ¿Y el argumento que expones aplica para todas las preguntas subjetivas?

Comment: @toledano Entiendo que su pregunta es genérica y pone un ejemplo especifico. Al menos yo me lo tomo así.

Answer (score 4):

> ## ¿Hay que cerrar todas las preguntas subjetivas?
>
> No.

## ¿Cuáles sí?

Las *preguntas de calidad* que aborden cuestiones con un alto grado de polarización, en particular, si implican posiciones políticas, religiosas, tradiciones o costumbres muy localizadas o preferencias personales.

Las [preguntas que no son de calidad](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/112/c%C3%B3mo-se-definen-las-preguntas-de-calidad), por ejemplo:

- preguntas de una sola línea de contenido medular y por ende no incluyen una breve descripción de lo buscado / investigado
- preguntas que incitan que el hilo se vuelva una "lista de compras"

## ¿Cuáles no?

Las que sean de valor para la comunidad ya sea por tratar de un tema difícil de encontrar o abordar en otro espacio, por abordar temas sobre las prácticas de la industria y que sean interesantes para los expertos reconocidos por la comunidad

## ¿Quiénes son los expertos reconocidos por la comunidad?

1. Expertos "orgánicos"

   - Los que tengan medallas de etiqueta en la etiqueta que corresponda a la pregunta
2. Expertos "estrellas"

   - Los [moderadores diamantados](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) del sitio en inglés y los [miembros con medallas de oro](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=gold)
   - Los expertos que tenga reconocimiento por organizaciones profesionales y/o instituciones
   - Líderes de opinión en la industria

Comment: Concuerdo con esta respuesta. Quizá personalmente pondría que la *mayoria* de preguntas subjetivas son indicativas de baja calidad o demasiado amplias ya que su planteamiento acostumbra a ser de bajo nivel. De vez en cuando, eso si, hay excepciones.

Comment: En lugar de ponerlo tal cual lo has sugerido, edité cuales sí para poner preguntas de calidad y preguntas que no son de calidad.

Answer (score 2):

Muy buen punto, y además respuestas de baja calidad tienen dos salidas: si no se pueden salvar, se pueden eliminar (o mejor aun votar -1 hasta que el autor se gana su medalla "presión de pares") o se pueden hacer comentarios informativos que permiten al autor de refacturar su respuesta hasta que queda una buena respuestas (que en si mismo es una tremenda fuente de aprendisaje para el autor tal cual que para los demás usuarios).